# Resume activity by itself

Tags: android, android-activity, timer, runnable

One activity. When home button pressed it will run OnPause method and after 5 sec activity show itself. This is what I want but couldn't. What is my mistake?

```
package cem.examples.listviewActivity;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class main extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(main.this, "Timer RUN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(main.this, "5000 msec ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intt = new Intent(main.this, main.class);
                        intt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intt);
                    }
                };
            }

        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: remove super.onPause() is a start.

Answer (score 2):

You have to start activity in a UI thread - not in ANY thread. Read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html

You would probably want to look for postDelayed there....

However you won't really get what you want probably - because onPause() is called on many different occasions (for example when you get sub-activity, or when you go to message from notification bar). What exactly is that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

There is now code in the system that prevents third party applications from popping up "soon" after the user presses the home key, because this was a technique that some apps were using to abuse the system.

Home is an important key for security -- it is the only sure way the user knows how to get to a UI they trust -- so we have a number of things to prevent applications from being able to cause the user to go somewhere different when home is pressed.